# Why doesn't the screen saver delay that I set persist after restarting my Mac?

Tags: macos, system-settings

I have a problem with a screen saver, I set it to 20 minutes and when I lock the computer and unlock it, the settings are unchanged. However, when I restart my mac, then the screen saver is set to default 5 minutes again.

Comment: Do you have a laptop (i.e. a Mac with a battery), and, if so, is it possible you set the screensaver delay while plugged in and restarted unplugged? I believe Adapter Power and Battery Power have two separate settings for the screen saver delay...

Comment: I tried this with my mac laptop plugged in only.

Answer (score 1):

Try repairing permissions with Disk Utility.

Comment: Why what dies that do?

Comment: In general, that can fix a wide variety of issues on OS X. I suggested it here especially because dt1510 reported that deleting the plist file made a difference. So it seems that perhaps the system does not have write permissions for that file.

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.desktop.plist` and logging out/in.

Comment: I did that and now the settings change to default even after just locking the computer.